# Why does dumping this JObject throw an AmbiguousMatchException in LINQPad?

Tags: json, json.net, linqpad, linq-to-json

When I run this code in LINQPad using JSON.NET:

```
var x = JObject.Parse(
@"{
  ""data"" : [ {
    ""id"" : ""bbab529ecefe58569c2b301a"",
    ""name"" : ""Sample Name"",
    ""group"" : ""8b618be8dc064e653daf62f9"",
    ""description"" : ""Sample Name"",
    ""payloadType"" : ""Geolocation"",
    ""contract"" : ""a9da09a7f4a7e7becf961865"",
    ""keepAlive"" : 0
  } ]
}");

x.Dump();
```

An `AmbiguousMatchException` is thrown when trying to dump the parsed JSON to LINQPad's output window. Why? As far as I can tell this is perfectly legitimate JSON. http://jsonlint.com/ says it's valid, too.

Comment: This is now fixed in LINQPad v5.09.03

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a problem with how `.Dump()` is implemented most likely.

If you check the stack trace:

```
at System.RuntimeType.GetInterface(String fullname, Boolean ignoreCase)
at System.Type.GetInterface(String name)
at UserQuery.Main()
...
```

We can see that the method throwing the exception is `System.RuntimeType.GetInterface`.

`System.RuntimeType` is one of the concrete classes used to represent `Type` objects when reflection is used at runtime, so let's check [`Type.GetInterface(String, Boolean)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tcctb9t8(v=vs.110).aspx) which has this to say:

> **AmbiguousMatchException**
>   The current Type represents a type that implements the same generic interface with different type arguments.

So it looks like the `GetInterface` method is called with a type of an interface that is implemented more than once, with different `T`'s or similar.

To provoke the same error, simply replace `x.Dump();` with this:

```
var type = x.GetType().GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1", true);
```

This will throw the same exception.

Here's a simpler [LINQPad](http://linqpad.net) example that shows the underlying problem:

```
void Main()
{
    var type = typeof(Problem).GetInterface("System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1", true);
}

public class Problem : IEnumerable<string>, IEnumerable<int>
{
    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator() => ((IEnumerable<string>)this).GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<string> IEnumerable<string>.GetEnumerator() => Enumerable.Empty<string>().GetEnumerator();
    IEnumerator<int> IEnumerable<int>.GetEnumerator() => Enumerable.Empty<int>().GetEnumerator();
}
```

This example will throw the exact same exception.

---

**Conclusion**: There is nothing wrong with the Json, nor with Json.Net, this is a problem with how LINQPad tries to figure out the best way to dump the object to the output window.

Comment: Hmm ok. Might be bug report time, then. I'll take this to the LINQPad forums.

Comment: I've shown a smaller example that shows the underlying problem, this would be more fit for the bug report I think, to avoid confusion with Json.net. That is, if you do: `new Problem().Dump();` then you have your bug report example, in addition to the `GetInterface` call, which shows which part of `Dump` that is problematic.

Comment: Spot on - thanks for the diagnosis. I'll publish a LINQPad fix tomorrow.

Comment: This is now fixed in LINQPad v5.09.03